# How do I set up the Crumbs trail For Commerce Kickstart Checkout?

Tags: breadcrumbs, commerce

Using Crumbs 7.x-1.10

During Checkout, the standard flow is 3 pages:

Cart ---> Shipping ---> Review

But at that last (3rd) step the Crumb trail shows

Home > Checkout > Checkout > Checkout

How do I set the Crumb trail to reflect the page H1s?

1. Is this done via the standard Setup page or 2. Does it require a plug-in? And if a plug-in can someone give me an example for this use case? Frankly, I'm having trouble understanding the nomenclature of both the std. Setup -and- the plug-ins of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You will have more luck with Crumbs 7.x-2.*.

See also

- [Use Crumbs 7.x-2.*, or tell people how to upgrade.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2409091) (Kickstart queue)
- [Commerce Kickstart Checkout Use Case](https://www.drupal.org/node/2408879) (Crumbs queue)

Comment: I updated to 7.x-2 and I'm more confused than ever. Can I -please-, PLEASE, PLEASE get a few minutes of your time via IRC or e-mail to get through my use case. I (literally) cannot figure out the 7.x-2 UI.